# REDHAWK Python component calls legacy C-code

Tags: redhawksdr

Is there a referred method of calling C-code from a Python component? I am porting to REDHAWK a csh script that calls C-code programs (with "main" entry points and argument lists). I prefer to implement the csh script as a Python component, from which I call the C-code programs.

Couple of notes:

1. I'm familiar with doing this in SWIG in GNU Radio.
2. I acknowledge the bigger issue of rearchitecting the entire system into connected SDR components, but the fundamental C-from-Python issue remains.

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting question.  Do you have access to the source code for the traditional "main" application?  Your statement about SWIG would suggest that you do.  If you do, the best approach may be to use the Shared Library pattern discussed in [Section 4.9](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch4.html#x6-970004.9) of the REDHAWK Manual.  The problem with either SWIG or the Shared Library approach is the that they require a restructuring of your legacy C application to effectively be a shared library.  If the legacy is just some form of batch processor that takes in commands and data and pushes out results, you may be best using a fork/exec paradigm.  I'm making huge assumptions here, but if your legacy app puts its output on stdout, you can just attach its stdout to a pipe that you read from in the component shell.

The REDHAWK GPP does the very thing I mention above for component applications and you can see how that is done [here](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/blob/develop-2.0/GPP/cpp/GPP.cpp#L1228)

I made a lot of assumptions in answering this.  If you provide more detail about your constraints I may be able to refine the answer.

*Additional Thought*: If you decide you just want a quick-result, there is a great post on StackOverflow under question 'python-c-wrapper-for-reading-variable-argument-lengths' that could probably get you up and running in a REDHAWK generated python component pretty quickly.  I'm just not sure how you would get any results from the legacy app.